# How to I write a "Date Between" query in the Mongo Java Driver?

Tags: mongodb

I have a query that works like a champ through the Javascript shell...

```
db.profiles.find(
  { "createdOn" :
    { $gte : ISODate( '2013-04-01T00:00:00.000Z' ),
      $lt : ISODate( '2013-04-02T00:00:00.000Z' )
    }
  }
)
```

.  How do I do this through the Java driver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried something like:

```
DBObject condition = new BasicDBObject(2);
condition.put("$gte", startDate);
condition.put("$lt", endDate);
Iterable<DBObject> result = collection.find(new BasicDBObject("createdOn", condition));
```

Comment: I have not and that looks promising.  I'll test it out, but I think we have a winner.